# Single Activity when posible (Google IO 2018) vs Activities per tasks?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm designing an app that make a psychological test. The app has 5 main parts: an intro slide screen, a main screen with the list of the completed test, the tests screens, the input data screens and the results screens.

Option 1: use a single activity responsable for handling all the fragments and flows. The problem is theres going to be like 30 fragments and different flows. For example if the user do a new test, the user has to answer 10 questions. When the user complete the questions if is not registered has to input his data and then can see his results but if the user is registered the result are shown directly.

Option 2: make an activity per part.

- Intro Activity: the intro slides.
- Main Activity: the list of the completed test with two main functions. A button new test and if you tap in a completed test you can see the results of that test or make a new test for that user.
- Test Activity: the group of questions to answer by the user.
- User Data Activity: the user data input.
- Results Activity: the test results.

In Google IO 2018 they suggest to use a single activity when possible but I think the option 2 it's much better in terms of OOP.

Comment: Kinda opinion-based, but I'd go for multiple activities to avoid having too much fragments and eventually lose some code/project readability. As long as the test itself isn't split into multiple activities I think you're on the good track anyway. I probably would have created three activities : Intro, Main and Test, and make only fragments for options, user data or results.

Answer (score 1):

In my honest opinion, You should go with **option 2**. As you mentioned in Google IO'18 they suggest to use single activity but you don't need to follow that for every use case. **Everyone** has **different** use case and issues. **Managing 30 fragments** in single activity can be tedious and code may get messy.

As you have categorized those fragments you can implement those in separate activity.

> Baseline here if it **works** for you. Just **go** with it.